# Weather Channel API support for videos

Tags: url, video, weather, media-channel

I am developing an iPad application in which I will be displaying weather information for location entered by the user. I am using Weather channel API for this.

Is it possible to get the video that shows weather of near-by locations of the location entered. (The Weather Channel Application is showing the video of the location say 'Atlanta'. The video shows weather conditions of near-by locations.)

If possible, how exactly I can get this video URL.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Deepa